# TimeSpan Showing only Hours?

Tags: c#, timespan

I have this problem in my MVC Application.

I have TimeSpan which contains for example 2 days 15 hours 31 minutes and 34 seconds.

I want to show only the hours/minutes/seconds and the thing is that I want to add the days to the hours like `63:31:34` .I tried to add a new time span like 
`time.Add(new TimeSpan(time.Days * 24, 0, 0)`,but the .NET add that like `2` days.

Can you help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

[`Hours` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.hours.aspx) can't be `63` since it's range from `-23` through `23`. You can get this `63:31:34` as a *textual* representation only using [`TimeSpan` properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_properties.aspx).

```
var ts = new TimeSpan(2, 15, 31, 34);
Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2}", (int)ts.TotalHours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
```

Prints;

```
63:31:34
```

As Jeppe [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109315/timespan-showing-only-hours#comment55971272_34109381) -not in your case- `ts.TotalHours` part can be limitted double precision since it's calculated as `(double)_ticks * HoursPerTick` based on the instance. In such a case, using `ts.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerHour` can be better way to produce `long / long` operation.

Comment: This comment is hardly relevant in practice, but for very large durations, such as `var ts = new TimeSpan(31557599999999999L)` (one hundred years!), you run into problems with the limited precision of `double`. Your code gives an incorrect result (off by one hour). In this case, use `string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", ts.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerHour, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds))` which I think works for arbitrarily large (positive) `TimeSpan` values.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Right, added as an addition. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Jeppes note, a method avoiding *double* could be to actively use the day count:

```
TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(1, 15, 42, 45, 750); 
Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2}", interval.Days * 24 + interval.Hours, interval.Minutes, interval.Seconds);

// result: 39:42:45
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding days use `TimeSpan.TotalHours` to display the time:

For example:

```
TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(1, 15, 42, 45, 750); 
Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2}", interval.TotalHours, interval.Minutes, interval.Seconds);
```

Comment: You would cast `interval.TotalHours` to `int` or otherwise truncate away the fractional part of that floating-point number.

Comment: Yes - or you will get: `39.7127083333333:42:45`.